# Mongodb aggregates: how to project a formatted filter

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I think it's not a difficult question but I'm not sure how to do it
My collection is

```
[
 { type:"bananas", weight:"1"},
 { type:"bananas", weight:"10"},
 { type:"apple", weight:"5"}
]
```

The result I would like to have is the count of each type in the same query, result expected:

```
{
  bananas: 2,
  apple: 1
}
```

We have 2 items of type "bananas" and 1 of type "apple" in the collection

So I guess I have to $project the props I want (item types) but I don't know how to count/sum/match this ?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $group: { _id: "$type", count: { $sum: 1 }} },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: [ [ { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } ] ]}
        }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
[{
    "apple" : 1.0
},
{
    "bananas" : 2.0
}]
```

Aggregation with merge

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $group: { _id: "$type", count: { $sum: 1 }} },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: [ [ { k: "$_id", v: "$count" } ] ]}
        }
    },
    { $facet: { items: [{$match: {} }]} },
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: "$items" } }
   },
])
```

Result:

```
[{
   "apple" : 1.0,
   "bananas" : 2.0
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$type",
            count: { $sum:1 },
            "data": {"$push": "$$ROOT" },
        }        
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "specList": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$data",
                        "as": "item",
                        "in": {
                            "k": "$$item.type",
                            "v": "$count",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }        
        }
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot:  { "$mergeObjects":[  "$specList" , { "item":"$_id"} ] } } }
])
```